# Python dictionary as html table in ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there any (existing) way to display a python dictionary as html table in an ipython notebook. Say I have a dictionary

```
d = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
```

then i run

```
magic_ipython_function(d)
```

to give me something like

[image]

Comment: Have a look at IPython rich display system: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb#HTML

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can write a custom function to override the default `_repr_html_` function.

```
class DictTable(dict):
    # Overridden dict class which takes a dict in the form {'a': 2, 'b': 3},
    # and renders an HTML Table in IPython Notebook.
    def _repr_html_(self):
        html = ["<table width=100%>"]
        for key, value in self.iteritems():
            html.append("<tr>")
            html.append("<td>{0}</td>".format(key))
            html.append("<td>{0}</td>".format(value))
            html.append("</tr>")
        html.append("</table>")
        return ''.join(html)
```

Then, use it like:

```
DictTable(d)
```

Output will be:
[image: Sample Output of DictTable]

If you are going to handle much bigger data (thousands of items), consider going with pandas.

Source of idea: [Blog post of ListTable](http://calebmadrigal.com/display-list-as-table-in-ipython-notebook/)

Comment: Small adjustment for python 3:  use `for key, value in iter(self.items()):` for the loop

Comment: Use `html.escape(str(key))` and `html.escape(str(value))` instead of `key` and `value`.

Answer (score 13):

You're probably looking for something like [ipy_table](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipy_table).

A different way would be to use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for a dataframe, but that might be an overkill.

Comment: Looks interesting,  especially the possibility to style the tables.

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't say pandas is an overkill, as you might use the DataFrame as a dict, among other things.

Anyway, you can do:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=d.keys())
```

Answer (score 6):

**Working Code:** Tested in Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.3.5

**In [1]:**

```
from ipy_table import *

# dictionary
dict = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}

# lists
temp = []
dictList = []

# convert the dictionary to a list
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictList.append(temp)

# create table with make_table
make_table(dictList)

# apply some styles to the table after it is created
set_column_style(0, width='100', bold=True, color='hsla(225, 80%, 94%, 1)')
set_column_style(1, width='100')

# render the table
render()
```

**Out [1]:**

[image: table screenshot]

**Get the generated html:**

**In [2]:**

```
render()._repr_html_()
```

**Out [2]:**

```
'<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"  style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td  style="background-color:hsla(225, 80%, 94%, 1);width:100px;"><b>a</b></td><td  style="width:100px;">2</td></tr><tr><td  style="background-color:hsla(225, 80%, 94%, 1);width:100px;"><b>b</b></td><td  style="width:100px;">3</td></tr></table>'
```

**References:**
http://epmoyer.github.io/ipy_table/
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/epmoyer/ipy_table/blob/master/ipy_table-Introduction.ipynb
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/epmoyer/ipy_table/blob/master/ipy_table-Reference.ipynb

Comment: Your `dictList` here is equivalent to `dict.items()`, is it not? I believe the for-loop and temporary variable are unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

A way to do it, but admittedly a hacky way, is to use *json2html*

```
from json2html import *
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(json2html.convert(json = {'a':'2','b':'3'}))
```

but it needs a third party library

Answer (score 2):

If you want later to externalise somewhere the HTML template and keep the control on it, it could be a good idea to use a **templating engine**. For this purpose you can use [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) (it's pretty much a standard in Python).

```
from jinja2 import Template
from IPython.display import HTML

d = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}

# content of the template that can be externalised
template_content = """
<table>
{% for key, value in data.items() %}
   <tr>
        <th> {{ key }} </th>
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>"""

template = Template(template_content)

# template rendering embedded in the HTML representation
HTML(template.render(data=d))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IPython Notebook will use the method `_repr_html_` to render HTML output of any object having a `_repr_html_` method

```
import markdown
class YourClass(str):
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return markdown.markdown(self)
d = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
rows = ["| %s | %s |" % (key, value) for key, value in d.items()]
table = "------\n%s\n------\n" % ('\n'.join(rows))
YourClass(table)
```

This solution needs the third part library `markdown`

Comment: That results in an `ImportError: No module named markdown` error

Comment: Ok my fault! I had a typo when looking for markdown at pypi.

Comment: The output didn't look helpful for this example - all on one line.  What did it look like for you?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it...

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display


def print_dict_as_html_table(some_dict):
    
        # create a list that will hold the html content  
        # initialise with the <table> tag
        html_list = ["<table>"]
        
        #iterate through the dictionary, appending row and element tags to the list
        for key in some_dict.keys():
            html_list.append("<tr>")
            html_list.append("<td>{0}</td>".format(key))
            html_list.append("<td>{0}</td>".format(some_dict[key]))
            html_list.append("</tr>")
            
        # add the final </table> tag to the list
        html_list.append("</table>")
        
        # create a string from the list
        html_string = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in html_list])

        #display the html 
        display(HTML(html_string))



dict1 = {1: 2, "foo": "bar", "cat": "dog"}

print_dict_as_html_table(dict1)
```

Image of the output:

[image: Output appearance in a notebook]